# Getting error while displaying a component in lazy loaded module in Angular

Tags: angular, typescript

I have created a component and its name is s-header. This component is registered in HomeModule because its a part of this module, but when i try to display this component in home.component.html it gives me this erorr.

***If 's-header' is an Angular component, then verify that it is part of this module.***

***If 's-header' is a Web Component then add 'CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component to suppress this message.***

here is my code

```
import { HeaderComponent } from '../../general-components/header/header.component';

declarations: [
    HeaderComponent,
],
```

this is a header component

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
    selector: 's-header',
    templateUrl: './header.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./header.component.css']
})
export class HeaderComponent implements OnInit {

    constructor() { }

    ngOnInit(): void {
    }
}
```

this is how i am trying to display it

```
<s-header></s-header>
```

Comment: Is that declarations array inside the module where you are using it?

Comment: yes it is inside that maodule

Comment: Can you provide a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)?

Comment: what version of angular is it? If it is angular 8 and lower you'll need to add it to entryComponents also

Answer (score 0):

If this is a version of Angular without Ivy - you'll need to also add this component into the [entry component](https://angular.io/guide/entry-components) array of the lazy loaded module. Its because the factory for this component doesn't exists (because its coming from a lazy loaded module)

Simply:

```
import { HeaderComponent } from '../../general-components/header/header.component';

declarations: [
    HeaderComponent,
...
],
entryComponents: [
    HeaderComponent
]
```

Comment: That's only necessary if it is a web component or a bootstrap component and the question did not indicate that was the situation.

Comment: In angular versions without Ivy - factories are created only for components that are declared in the html or in entryComponents. So I don’t follow @Silvermind, do I miss something?

Comment: And since this is a lazy module, the html declaration doesn’t count

Comment: A typical Angular application has no entry components at all. The only time you needed it, was when you manually used ngDoBootstrap(). There are a few exceptions, but those do not apply in this case, even so for a lazy loaded module. If you want to now how they work, here is the link: [Entry components](https://angular.io/guide/entry-components)